# some issues with isin() accuracy

Tags: python, pandas

I have some issues with `isin()` function accuracy.

I have along with `abc` many `IDs` in my `DataFrame`:

```
df = DataFrame[DataFrame['id'].isin(IDs)]
```

but the result of:

```
print('abc' in df['id']) 
>> False
```

and the result of:

```
print('abc' in df['id'].unique())
>> True
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: I can't upload my own data because of security reason, but i will try to make a sample

Comment: Is IDs actually a list or a pandas Series? If it’s a series the in statement is evaluating against the index values of the series and that is your problem. Your next statement is then evaluating against the values of this container. **Edit:**Actually, this is explained in @jezrael answer which I have now upvoted, although my guess is that the problem is IDs is a pandas series and not a list.

Comment: It is <class 'list'> , but my main problem is still unsolved and it is about isin() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is problem if use `in` with `Series` tests for membership in the index, [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#using-the-in-operator).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['abc','sdf','ert']}, index=['s','d','f'])
print (df)
    id
s  abc
d  sdf
f  ert

print('abc' in df['id'])
False
print('abc' in df['id'].index)
False
```

So if test numpy array created by [`Series.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) it working like expected:

```
print(type(df['id'].values))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

print('abc' in df['id'].values)
True
```

So if test index values:

```
print('d' in df['id'])
True
print('d' in df['id'].index)
True
```

EDIT: If use [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) it return `numpy array`:

```
print(df['id'].unique())
['abc' 'sdf' 'ert']

print(type(df['id'].unique()))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

print('abc' in df['id'].unique())
True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer 
but why the result ```print('abc' in df['id'].values)``` is True in my Question? After the filtration that i had done

Comment: @Amir.S - Do you think `df['id'].unique()` ? Becuase it return numpy array, not `Series`

Comment: @Amir.S - I just read comment under question, your problem is not resolved. Can you explain why? Is necessary something explain more?

Comment: sorry for my late answer , that was my mistake , i had 435 (as integer) and "435" (as string) in my data which i wasn't aware , thanks my problem solved.

Comment: How can i accept the answer? Your answer was right.